# Error while installing Oracle Data Access Components for .Net

Tags: oracle, odac

I am trying to install **64 bit Oracle Data Access Components (12.1.0.2.1) for .Net**. While installation i am getting the error in Prerequisite checks. In prerequisite check it check for Free space, Architecture and Environment variable Path.

> For architecture parameter, error is System Architecture Could not be determined

and for

> Environment parameter, error is Environment variable value could not be determined

I am trying to install it on Windows 8.1.  Please suggest how to resolve the issue.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Windows Server 2012.

Running the setup.exe as Administrator solved it for me.